# pointer arithemetic while using an array of double

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

So I have a pointer to an array of doubles, what I need to do is us pointer arithmetic to move to next place in the array, however I cant find any decent documentation on how to do this.

This is my current line keep in mind that temperatures array is a pointer array that looks like this `double *temperaturesArray = new double[daysToPrompt];`

```
cout << setw(10)<< counter + 1 << setw(10) << temperaturesArray + counter << "\370C" <<setw(10) << getFahrenheit(temperaturesArray + counter) <<"\370F"<< endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct array element is `temperaturesArray + counter` as you have in your code.  Unfortunately, that is just a pointer.  You'll want to **dereference** the pointer for printing or for whenever you want the double *value* rather than the *pointer*:

```
cout << setw(10) << counter + 1 << setw(10) << *(temperaturesArray + counter) << "\370C" << setw(10) << getFahrenheit(*(temperaturesArray + counter)) << "\370F" << endl;
```

This is counter-intuitive though.  When you get past this assignment just index the array ;-).

```
cout << setw(10) << counter + 1 << setw(10) << temperaturesArray[counter] << "\370C" << setw(10) << getFahrenheit(temperaturesArray[counter]) << "\370F" << endl;
```

Look up **pointer dereferencing** in any decent C++ book.  It should be there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write any pointer arithmetic. Just index into the array with the `[]` operator.

```
cout << setw(10)<< counter + 1
     << setw(10) << temperaturesArray[ counter ] << "\370C"
     <<setw(10) << getFahrenheit(temperaturesArray[ counter ]) <<"\370F"
     << endl;
```

This would go inside a loop, also including at some point `++ counter`.

This is how arrays (and similar structures like `std::vector`) are most commonly used.

**EDIT:** If at some point your teacher gave the arbitrary requirement to use "pointer arithmetic," you have two options:

- Note that `temperaturesArray[ counter ]` directly translates to `*( temperaturesArray + counter)` so you are already using pointer arithmetic, just not in an explicit way. You can also do `counter[ temperaturesArray ]` to demonstrate this to the teacher.
- Write `++ temperaturesArray` instead of `++ counter` and use `temperaturesArray[0]` or `*temperaturesArray` instead of `temperaturesArray[counter]`. This is bad programming practice, though. Shame on your lazy teacher for not telling you what to do, or why, when doing so is also a bad idea.

Comment: Im being required to use pointer arithmetic sadly, I just dont know how to do it

Comment: Cant find any decent documentation on it either, seems like it shouldnt be that hard

Answer (score 0):

> Im being required to use pointer arithmetic sadly

Then any expression such as

```
temperaturesArray[ counter ]
```

can be replaced with

```
*(temperaturesArray + counter )
```

With arrays, these are functionally identical.